# How to check if one component works well without having to place other component's data?

Tags: reactjs

The data of page template is very different from my API.

So, I split the page template into several components.

I have completed data placement of one component to be compatible with my API.

I want to check if the component works well.

But, In React, If data doesn't match a component, an error occurs and rendering is not possible.

Can I confirm only that component is working?

I commenting out other components manually. This is a very cumbersome task.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing that and guaranteeing that your API is working with your components. I'll list the ones I know here and you can use what fits you best. Some of them can be even combined between themselves!

### Normalization

You can use a concept called "normalization of data". You normalize the data once, right after receiving it from the request, and use it already normalized.

Let's say you receive the data at your "page" component and right after receiving it you normalize it. It'll be something similar to this(this code will not work, it is just the idea of it!):

```js
import normalize from "./normalize-api-data";

// ...

const [normalizedData, setNormalizedData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  const data = fetch();
  setNormalizedData(normalize(data));
}, []);
```

#### Centralize your App State

If you start to have lots of components that depend on some data, you'll face issues such as passing a lot of data to child components that don't make sense and a lot of props without meaning to that component.

Use something like ContextAPI or Redux and you can get your state at the components you need.

Combine it with the normalization approach and you'll have one request and one source of truth for your App Data.

#### Use Types!

TypeScript is a great way of knowing where things are not the type they should be. If you receive something that is not in the same state that you are expecting and normalizing, your type will warn you.

#### Use React Query

React Query is a great tool to make and caching requests. You can use it to simulate a "global state" and "API" at the same place. If you combine it with normalization, it is even more powerful!

#### Create Fallbacks

Error Boundaries, Empty States, Warnings with Toasts, and other approaches could help you to not get into a flaky state. This is a simple code that prevents from breaking:

```
function Page({ data }) {
  if (!data?.user) {
    return <EmptyState type="no-user" />
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <UserInfo user={data.user} />
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```